# Initramfs boot stuck

Tags: 20.04, boot-repair, luks, initramfs

I currently encounter the initramfs on boot "error". I tried several hours to recover from it.

At the first place I got the error, **`/dev/mapper/root` does not exist**. I got rid of that with this steps:

1. Boot into a live distro.
2. `cryptsetup open /dev/nvmexxxx` - get access to my nvme.
3. mount the root, usr, tmp, var, dev, sys, proc and boot into `/mnt`.
4. `chroot /mnt`
5. execute this command `update-initramfs -u -k all` and than `update-grub` as well.
6. reboot

Now I do not get any alerts at all and the prompt wont show up, where I can enter my password for the nvme to "unlock".

The only clue I have is, when I boot up in recovery mode. `Cannot process volume group vg00`. I am not able to find anything in the internet about this error. Also I checked my `/etc/crypttab` as well and there is the right UUID. I also checked `/etc/fstab`, if I named the tag from `cryptsetup` wrong, but this neither.

I also tried this bash [script](https://gist.github.com/dragon788/e777ba64d373210e4f6306ad40ee0e80), but with no success.

-- Update output of `vgdisplay vg00` --
| Name     | Name     |
|:------:|:------:|
|VG Name|               vg00|
|System ID| |
|Format|                lvm2|
|Metadata Areas|        1|
|Metadata Sequence No|  11|
|VG Access            | read/write|
|VG Status             |resizable|
|MAX LV            |    0|
|Cur LV             |   6|
|Open LV             |  6|
|Max PV               | 0|
|Cur PV            |   1|
|Act PV             |   1|
|VG Size             |  <476.27 GiB|
|PE Size              | 4.00 MiB|
|Total PE             | 121925|
|Alloc PE / Size     |  121925 / <476.27 GiB|
|Free  PE / Size      | 0 / 0   |
|VG UUID              | affkCZ-Y9aU-7r3p-dTxo-5Y0A-u91e-Nhubij|

Thank in advance!

Comment: Can you add the output of `vgdisplay vg00` to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK now I got everything to work. The solution below just worked for me, because a new **linux version** was available.

The solution was:

Do the steps I described earlier and be aware of the naming of the label while executing the `cryptsetup open /dev/nvmexxxx` command. To be sure, you have the right name, make a look up at `/etc/crypttab`. It should looks like something like this: `label_name UUID=your_id none luks,discard`. Write it done or remember the **label_name**. Reboot the system and manually unlock the disk with the exact same **label_name**. After that `exit` and it will boot normally into your OS. In your OS open a terminal and type in `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`. After that run the command `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` to update your initramfs. Now it should work.