# Ubuntu 20.04 is not booting as stuck at initramfs

Tags: boot, mount, initramfs

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I checked the posts like [Stuck at initramfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309916/stuck-at-initramfs-after-system-updateubuntu-20-04), [Busybox initramfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020872/busybox-initramfs-again-and-again) and [boot stuck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356937/initramfs-boot-stuck) which did not provide any solution. So it is not wise to mark this question as repeat question unless you are able to provide any successful solution. In my case, `blkid` or `exit` does not show anything and shows `(initramfs)` prompt again. As usual, `reboot` is not working. The command `df` shows `udev` and `tmpfs` filesystem. The second solution in the [second link above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020872/busybox-initramfs-again-and-again) advice to use ubuntu live disk and in the terminal, it advices to use `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb#` partition which is under linux filesystem. However, that command reports it is not possible as it is mounted. The `df -h` command shows only mounted disk by ubuntu live and not partition in installed ubuntu. In reference [boot stuck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356937/initramfs-boot-stuck), it adviced to open `/etc/crypttab`. Since the original root is not mounted, I am not getting anything. The command `sudo chroot /mnt` does not work in livecd terminal.

Please advice how may I proceed.
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution suddenly.
Since I have a dual boot, I wanted to boot into Windows 10 and I was surprised to blue screen (BSOD) reporting windows issue. Finally I thought to re-install ubuntu and started to re-install. Then the installation wizard reported ubuntu is unable to install with RAID. This is strange. My system is working since Aug, 2021. Then in the BIOS configuration setup I found RAID is on. I changed it to AHCI mode and tried to see what happens after the reboot. I checked windows 10 and it opened superbly. Then I tried to reboot in ubuntu and it showed login screen immediately without any issue. I am surprised. The issue is resolved.